# Trying to upload a .doc file but I'm always getting a Request Timeout

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, lamp

When I upload a .doc file to the server, it always gives a Timeout error. Locally it works and with doc and docx too.

This is not really a application problem because the upload process doesn't even reach the app itself.

It is not a max file size or max upload error.

Error Message:

> Request Timeout Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the
> client.
>
> Apache/2.4.43 (Ubuntu) Server at digitalsign.grupoch.pt Port 80

So far what I did was edit the mime.conf file inside mods-enable folder and added the following:

```
AddType application/msword .doc
```

Restarted apache but that didn't do any good either.

I'm running apache in version 2.4.43 under Ubuntu Server version 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

This probably has something to do with the protection layer apache has when you upload .doc files and they might have code in them.

This can probably be solved by just installing a certificate and using your app as HTTPS instead of HTTP.

They are free and you can probably just use something like this to do so:

https://certbot.eff.org/